# Create a matrix of four-dimensional space rotate counterclockwise by the angle π / 3 around the plane

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, numerical-linear-algebra

Create a matrix of four-dimensional space rotate counterclockwise by the angle   $\frac{π}{3}$ around the plane

\begin{cases}
x − y + t = 0,\\[2ex]
y + z + t = 0
\end{cases}

on the basis of unit vectors.

---

How can I solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: A helpful first step is to find an orthonormal basis for this plane.